# Silverlight InitParams, "localhost" converts to "::1"?

Tags: silverlight, parameters, init

I have a silverlight application and am using init params to pass an API server URL through from my web config to the host page to the App.xaml.cs

The API url contains "localhost" then a port number.
But when it gets to the App.xaml.cs in debug mode it's being passed in as "::1" then the port number.

Why is this? Any way other than simply checking for "::1" and converting it back to "localhost"?

*edit*

This is the hosted page's markup where I send the init params.

```
 <param name="initParams" value="<%=string.Format("APIServer={0}, PivotServer={1}", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["APIServer"],ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PivotServer"] ) %>" />
```

This is where I extract the init params:

```
private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
{
    apiServer = e.InitParams["APIServer"];
}
```

Comment: But "::1" is `localhost` - in IPv6.

Comment: I realize that after a google search, but that doesn't help the problem at hand. I'm passing that in so that for further usage within the SL app, I can make calls to that API for data retrieval/persistence/etc.

I can't make a web call to "http://::1/MYAPI".

It works fine if I simply check for "::1" and replace it with "localhost" once inside my SL app startup, but this is just a hack.

Comment: `::1` is the equivalent of `127.0.0.1`/`localhost` in IPv6

Comment: Again, I realize that after a google search, but that doesn't help the problem at hand. I'm passing that in so that for further usage within the SL app, I can make calls to that API for data retrieval/persistence/etc. I can't make a web call to "http://::1/MYAPI". It works fine if I simply check for "::1" and replace it with "localhost" once inside my SL app startup, but this is just a hack.

Comment: to use IPv6 in the browser (and I presume, in SL) you have to enclose the v6 address in square backets (eg.  http://[::1]/MYAPI)

Comment: Show us the code you are using to assign the InitParams server-side, include where you get the servername/IP address from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm simply checking for it and changing it at runtime.